# Extracting data from vue-chartjs into an array of datasets

Tags: javascript, callback, vue.js

I have a function which returns an array of datasets for a chart written with vue-chartjs. The getter `getChartData` returns an array with three objects with nested objects. I see that my function has a so called 'callback hell' and I want to refactor this.

```
getDatasets() {
  let datasetLabels = [];
  const obj = this.getChartData;
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((entry) => {
    datasetLabels = [...datasetLabels, ...Object.keys(entry[1])];
  });
  let datasets = [];
  [...new Set(datasetLabels)].forEach((item, index, arr) => {
    datasets.push({ label: item, backgroundColor: this.getColor(arr, index), data: [] });
  });
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((el) => {
    const datasetData = Object.entries(el[1]);
    datasetData.forEach(
      (item) => {
        datasets = datasets.map((e) => {
          if (e.label === item[0]) {
            e.data.push(item[1].median);
          }
          return e;
        });
      });
  });
  return datasets;
},
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: No need to wait until next time - you can still [edit] to improve your question (but we don't allow you to change the actual *code* once you've received an answer!).

Comment: Already done. :)

Comment: Please take note of the link that Toby provided, it states: "`Use a title that is catchy, and describes the problem your code solvesUse a title that is catchy, and describes the problem your code solves`"  please describe what the code does in your title, not an issue you wish to resolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## False alarm! No callback hell here.

While this code can certainly be refactored a bit, I fail to see *callback hell* anywhere around. *Callback hell* is normally a term applied to the code that is executed *asynchronously* and with multiple nested callback functions. The nested structure is what causes a few issues:

- cognitive complexity (which leads to bugs and maintenance complication);
- refactoring difficulty;
- more importantly, hard time expressing conditional ("branching") or cyclic ("loops") logic.

A related [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098066/what-is-callback-hell-and-how-and-why-rx-solves-it) might be helpful (just don't focus on RxJs part of the answer there).

Your code does actively use arrow functions, but it is not equivalent to callback hell. The number one reason is because everything in `getDatasets()` is executed synchronously.

## Refactoring

### Nitpicking

- Small details like line breaks are powerful. Splitting the function into paragraphs with empty line separators helps identifying logical steps you're making in code. It also can work help in extracting sub-functions later, if/when the function becomes too long.
- Naming things: Spelling things out is always better than using names like `el`, `e`, `arr`. Abbreviated variable names like that suggest that these entities have no reason to exist or are unimportant. Even `item` is not a good name. Since it denotes a label, call it a `label`. I'm sure you got the idea.
- Naming continued: Name your variables consistently. You iterate two times over the same object: `Object.entries(obj).forEach(...)` in one case you call the current entry as `entry`, while in the other – just `el`. That is confusing.
- I like how you lock down the chart data in a locally scoped `obj` variable. Renaming it to `chartData` would make it more readable, though.
- You could also avoid `let` in a few places and have `const` instead. For example, `reduce(...)` or `map(...)` are in many cases a better alternative to `for (...)` or `.forEach(...)`.
- Also, be careful when you deal with array deconstruction. While it's readable, it's also very inefficient because it creates a new array by iterating all the elements of the source arrays. It's only fine to use it for pieces of code that are not invoked frequently and/or operate on tiny arrays only.

### Applying the suggestions to the code

I could only rewrite the first half of the function. The second half requires a broader context to make a meaningful change to it.

As you can see, I failed to rename `e` into something descriptive, because I'm unaware of the models you are using in your application. Hopefully, even this "mechanical" refactoring is able to give you some ideas on how the code can be improved.

```
getDatasets() {
  const chartData = this.getChartData;

  const datasetLabels = Object.values(chartData);

  // `datasets` could be a const, if only it wasn't modified further down the road...
  let datasets = [...new Set(datasetLabels)]
    .map((label, labelIndex, array) => ({ label, backgroundColor: this.getColor(array, labelIndex), data: [] }));

  // This is a subject to a few more changing, maybe...
  Object
    .entries(chartData)
    .forEach((entry) => {
      Object.entries(entry[1]).forEach((dataItem) => {
          datasets = datasets.map((e) => {
            if (e.label === dataItem[0]) {
              e.data.push(dataItem[1].median);
            }
            return e;
          });
        });
    });

  return datasets;
}
```

**Update** As @Gerrit0 suggested, `Object.values(...)` is a better option than `Object.entities(...).map(...)` (more concise and achieves exactly the same result).

Comment: @OlgaB sure! Glad to help.

Comment: Given that you never use `entry[0]`, it might be worth switching to `Object.values`